# ¿Cómo hacer un INSERT en SQL a partir de una Subconsulta que depende de un parámetro?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, netbeans-8.2

vengo a pedirles ayuda con una misión que creo que será imposible, aunque en programación no hay nada imposible. Mi idea es hacer una app desktop en Java que me genere el 10% de la cantidad de inventario por almacén, lo cual ya esta implementado en código, pero el cliente desea que una vez listado el 10% de ese almacen en específico, esa información se guarde como ya usada (digamos que como ya listada) y pueda volver a realizar la consulta con datos nuevos. Cabe destacar que cada almacén tiene miles de datos, y cada dia se insertan nuevos datos.

En mi aplicación yo genero un reporte en un Jtable de los productos por almacén. El código que uso para sacar el 10 porciento de productos en almacen es este:

```
SELECT TOP(10) PERCENT Id_Producto, Desc_Producto, UM_Almacen, Seccion, Estante, Casilla
FROM      Inventario.dbo.Producto_Listado
WHERE Id_Almacen = '802A'
ORDER BY Fecha_Entrada
```

Llamo a los respectivos almacenes desde un método en Java, cambiando únicamente el Id del almacén que quiero revisar en ese momento

[image: mi proyecto]

Este código funciona a la perfección. Cuál es mi idea? Que una vez mostrado el listado en ese Jtable, al hacer click en el botón actualizar se me haga un Update de esos datos en mi tabla en SQL. Esta tabla es el resultado de un JOIN de varias tablas mas, el cual guarde en esa tabla en especifico para tener un campo de Listado. A mi tabla en SQL le agregre una columna llamada Listado, de tipo bit y mi idea es cuando se haga el update ponerla con valor = 1 (inicialmente tiene valor nulo ya que aun no se ha echo ningun reporte)

[image: mi tabla en sql]

Mi idea seria un código asi:

```
update Listado set Listado=1
  where Id_Producto=
   (select p.codigo
from Producto p
join Producto_Listado
on Id_Producto=p.Id_Producto);
```

El ID de producto lo comparo con la tabla Producto (donde estan todos los id de los productos) dado que es único para cada producto. Tenia pensado comparar también con el ID del almacen pero dado que es un parámetro que llamo en una consulta SQL no se bien como especificarlo.

Por supuesto después tendria que incluir en el código que cuando vaya a sacar el 10% sea de los articulos que aun no hayan sido listados, algo asi:

```
SELECT TOP(10) PERCENT Id_Producto, Desc_Producto, UM_Almacen, Seccion, Estante, Casilla
FROM      Inventario.dbo.Producto_Listado
WHERE Id_Almacen = '802A' and Listado !=1
ORDER BY Fecha_Entrada
```

Comment: El update que tienes se ve bien, pero si lo que necesitas es agregar el id de almacen, puedes usar un UPDATE FROM, en este articulo puedes encontrar un ejemplo: https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-update-from-a-select-statement-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 2):

Hay una manera para dividir toda la tabla en porciones de 10%. Luego vas pidiendo la porción que te interesa (la 1/10, la 2/10, .. la 10/10)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT *,
     NTILE(10) OVER (ORDER BY Fecha_Entrada) AS ntile
FROM Inventario.dbo.Producto_Listado
) sub
WHERE sub.ntile = 1; // <- porción que quieres, del 1 al 10
                     // un 11 te devuelve vacío, claro.
```

Un saludo!

Comment: Pero eso no toma en cuenta los cambios que pueda recibir la tabla entre una consulta y otra.

Comment: pues se filtra esta consulta para todos los campos hasta la fecha de inicio de la revisión de la BD. una vez terminada solo hará falta revisar los nuevos datos.